# ConcurrentHashMap.Segment is-a-ReentrantLock?

Tags: java, class-design, concurrenthashmap

On the design of `ConcurrentHashMap.Segment` in Java 1.6 collection library  :

```
  static final class Segment<K,V> extends ReentrantLock implements Serializable
```

IMHO , a given `Segment` is-not-a `ReentrantLock` , then why this `extends` ? It should have been a composition :

`static final class Segment<K,V> implements Serializable { 
     ReentrantLock lock = ... 
   }`

Answer (score 4):

The javadoc says:

> Segments are specialized versions of hash tables.  This subclasses
>   from ReentrantLock opportunistically, just to simplify some locking
>   and avoid separate construction.

Given that it's a non-public inner class, I guess they made a tradeoff between performance, ease-of-use, and good design.

Answer (score 2):

The comments before it are your best explanation.

```
/**
 * Segments are specialized versions of hash tables.  This
 * subclasses from ReentrantLock opportunistically, just to
 * simplify some locking and avoid separate construction.
 */
```